# Opera 10 bookmark sync

Tags: bookmarks, opera, opera-10

Is anyone else having problems with Opera 10's Sync, particularly bookmarks?  I Sync my bookmarks and speed dial, and speed dial seems to be fine.  However, my bookmarks are empty.  When I login to http://live.opera.com though, I see that all my bookmarks are still there.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, did you find a fix?

Comment: Same version, I haven't encountered such problem. The only problem I had once with bookmarks, was because of wrong timestamps (I guess), leading to have my bookmarks wiped on server, from an alpha of Opera 10 which though its empty list was more recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, as a solution, would be :

- Backup (or just delete) the cache and user folders created by Opera (they can be found in the C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Opera\Opera in Windows XP, and something close in Vista and Seven, if someone could precise).
- Uninstall Opera
- Reinstall it

It seems to me like something went wrong in the configuration files, and if so, that would be a solution, I guess. Opera Sync works good, so far I have seen it, so maybe it's a local problem which would be solved this way.

If not, then it will probably require more investigation of your computer's configuration, and how your network is handled (though I doubt it would be a problem if you can access web pages).

Comment: That worked, but I wonder how it got that way in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

A nightmare here with Bookmarks.

It seems that my bookmarks file is corrupted. It appears to be fine if I don't enable the Opera link feature, but the moment I do it all the bookmarks are moved outside their original location, the folders are duplicated and many of them empty.

I have been trying to solve this issue deleting the bookmarks from all the instances of Opera, import from a backup and then synchronize, but all I get is a total disorder on bookmarks and folders, all messed up.

Also have tried to import the same file on all the computers, but it's even worse.